# ¿Cómo invocar una función que no está en la misma carpeta?

Tags: python, python-3.x

He creado un archivo (módulo) "funciones.py" con funciones que quiero usar con diferentes programas que están en diferentes carpetas (01.py, 02.py, 03.py). La estructura del árbol es algo así:

```
Python 3
    funciones
        funciones.py
    01
        01.py
    02
        02.py
    03
        03.py
```

He buscado información y he visto que para poder invocar una función de las que hay dentro de "funciones.py" desde cualquier otro programa, tengo que incluir un archivo "**init**.py" en la carpeta en la que está "funciones.py". Lo he hecho y el árbol me queda del siguiente modo:

```
Python 3
    funciones
        funciones.py
        __init__.py
    01
        01.py
    02
        02.py
    03
        03.py
```

Si por ejemplo abro "01.py" e importo el archivo de funciones `import funciones as fun` y después invoco una de las funciones `fun.saludo()` me da error porque no se ha importado el módulo.

Aclaro que si pongo "funciones.py" en la misma carpeta que uno de los programas (01,02 ó 03), entonces puedo invocarla desde el programa de esa carpeta sin problema.

¿Qué tengo que hacer para poder importar el módulo "funciones.py" desde cualquier otro archivo .py?

PD: Trabajo con Spuder 3 a través de Anaconda.

Comment: debiera haber un `__init__.py`  en cada subcarpeta para poder usarlas como si fueran módulos

Comment: Sí, eso es lo que he hecho en la carpeta "funciones". Todos los módulos que voy a necesitar los voy a guardar en esa carpeta. Pero no me deja importar "funciones.py"

Comment: Zhisi depende de que relación tengan tus módulos entre ellos ¿Es todo lo que muestras un paquete?  ¿O no tienen relación entre si (`01`, `02`, `03` y `funciones` son paquetes independientes) y pretendes ejecutar directamente `0.py` como un módulo principal?

Comment: @FJSevilla Dentro de ´Python 3´ guardo todos mis proyectos de Python. ´01.py´, ´02.py´ y ´03.py´ son tres proyectos diferentes (cada uno de ellos es un "main" o módulo principal) y ´funciones´ quiero que sea un paquete con módulos que puedan ser llamados desde cualquier otro proyecto dentro de ´Pyton 3´.

Comment: Lo he solucionado utilizando "PYTHONPATH". He añadido a "PYTHONPATH" la ruta en la que se encuentra el módulo. No he necesitado ningún archivo ´__init__.py´.

Comment: @Zhisi Lo que estás diciendo es que no encontraba el módulo `funciones` porque no estaba en las rutas de búsqueda de módulos. Todo lo demás es irrelevante.

Comment: @ChemaCortes ¿Siempre se puede hacer así, poniendo la ruta en la búsqueda de módulos?¿No es necesario crear archivos `__init__.py` para que encuentre los módulos?

Comment: @Zhisi Los paquetes tienen sentido para agrupar módulos en una jerarquía. En cuanto a manipular las rutas de búsqueda, hay varias formas de hacerlo (Mírate el *muy-desconocido* [módulo site](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/site.html), por ejemplo)

Comment: @ChemaCortes He leído el contenido del enlace y aunque se escapa a mis conocimientos, para hacerme una idea me ha venido bien. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer ya ha encontrado una solución con **PYTHONPATH**:

> Lo he solucionado utilizando "PYTHONPATH". He añadido a "PYTHONPATH" la ruta en la que se encuentra el módulo. No he necesitado ningún archivo `__init__.py` – Zhisi

Pero hay otra alternativa similar, tomando en cuenta la siguiente estructura de árbol:

```
python3\
 funciones\
   __init__.py
   funciones.py
 01\
   01.py
 02\
   02.py
 03\
   03.py
```

y asumiendo que reestructurar no es una opción. Usted puede utilizar `sys.path.append('/path/')` de la siguiente manera:

**01.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
sys.path.append('../funciones/')
import funciones as fun 

resultado = fun.suma(5, 5)
print (resultado)
```

Simplemente se agregar el subdirectorio ('/python3/funciones') al `path` de Python, con el fin de intentar importar de una manera un tanto normal.

Comment: La primera alternativa que planteas no me funciona y no sé por qué. En el caso de usar `sys.path.append()` ¿no es otra forma de añadir directorios a PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Creo que te he confundido un poco con mi respuesta (culpa mía), solo he planteado resolver el problema con `sys.path.append()`. Y si es correcto! es otra forma de agregar directorios al `path`, pero creo que de este modo es mas practico, debido a que si modificas el **PYTHONPATH** y mueves de lugar el directorio `python3\` te generara el mismo error.

Comment: Entonces, si lo hago con PYTHONPATH ¿es relevante el directorio en donde esté ´python 3´ para que encuentre el directorio donde almaceno las funciones?

Comment: Así es, supongo que usted hizo algo *similar* a esto: `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:${HOME}/code/python3"`. Si por ejemplo mueve el directorio **python3** a ${HOME}/Documentos/ e intenta ejecutar uno de sus scripts, nuevamente python no lograra encontrar el modulo **funciones.py**.