# Se puede importar un modulo en otro modulo en carpetas hermanas

Tags: python-3.x

Mi pregunta seria:
es posible importar un modulo en carpetas hermanas que estan en el directorio padre, esta es la estructura:

```
-Golosinas-
    main.py
      carpeta1
        __init__.py
        mod1.py
      carpeta2
        __init__.py
        mod2.py
```

digamos que mod1.py tiene:

```
def run():
    print("hola mundo")
```

quisiera importarlo en mod2.py y ejecutar la funcion, pero no me sale, ayudenme porfavor
este es lo que encuentro y no me sirve:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
from carpeta1 import mod1
```

tmb lo he hecho asi

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
from carpeta1.mod1 import run
```

o asi

```
from ..carpeta1.mod1 import run
```

y cualquier cosa que me encontraba y ninguna funciono
AYUDA!!! PLEASE!!!

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Antes de publicar una pregunta es importante revisar si hay otras preguntas relacionadas al problema, en este caso el tema se ha tratado múltiples veces, aquí te dejo algunas preguntas relacionadas
[¿Cómo invocar una función que no está en la misma carpeta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/122385/171630)
[Importar modulo desde una carpeta del mismo nivel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/538621/171630)